# Iterate over each object In array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following js code:

```
 $http.get($rootScope.appUrl + '/nao/system/getUserBox/' + $routeParams['id']).success(function(data) {
        $scope.userbox = data;
    });
```

$scope.userbox can contain one, or several objects. In this case, result for the user Is only one object:

```
 Object { mac="00:22:07:2A:8D:4B", type="ZAP100", serial="D15024H12B034568", more...}
```

The thing I want to do Is to print out Box for each OBJECT, not object property, In the array result.

I have tried like this:

```
<h5 class="bg-primary rmpad15" ng-repeat="userbox in userbox">Box</h5>
```

But this result In 19 rows of -elements, which Is for each object property, which Is wrong. If the array contains only one object, then I want ONE -element to be printed.

Comment: Try to add the result data to an array if it's an object and not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test the return value for *arrayness*, and wrap it in an array if it is an object:

```
$scope.userbox = Array.isArray( data ) ? data : [ data ];
```

This approach should work in Internet Explorer 9 and newer. If, for whatever reason, you need support for `Array.isArray` in earlier versions of IE, you can [polyfill it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 0):

If you make sure the backend always returns the single or multiple objects in an array, you should be golden!